# TYPO3 extension select record when including plugin as content element

Tags: typo3

How do I select an item from storage folder, when including a frontend plugin as content element?

I have made an extension (or am trying to make), that will save blocks in a folder, that can be used on several pages.

When adding a frontend plugin to a page, and selecting the extension, I want to be able to select a record that should be displayed there...

I've been trying to set up Flexforms, but still haven't got any result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the FlexForm is the typical place to store additional settings of inserted plugin and most comfortable for normal BE editors.

On the other hand, if you are the only one who'll administrate that page (with full admin access) and you don't need to paste this plugin more than once on the page you can also save the uid of the default record in TypoScript - `setup` field of the template included on the required page.

Something like

```
plugin.tx_yourext_pi1.initialRecordUid=123
```

or for Extbase

```
plugin.tx_yourext.settings.initialRecordUid=123
```

While you didn't tell us how are you gonna to create the extension, we can't help you better.

Answer (score 0):

There is a content element called "insert records". Perhaps that is, what you need?

If you need your extension, just paste some code. It is easier to help then.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it by flexform you can use following way,

```
<selectProperty>
  <TCEforms>
  <label>Select property</label>
  <displayCond>FIELD:WhichPage:=:Home</displayCond>
   <config>
   <type>select</type>
   <foreign_table>Your table name</foreign_table>
   <foreign_table_where>AND  (your table name.deleted = 0) AND  (your table name.hidden = 0) AND  (tx_wellnessproperty_property.sys_language_uid = CAST('###REC_FIELD_sys_language_uid###' AS UNSIGNED) OR sys_language_uid = '-1' ) ORDER BY your table name.uid DESC  </foreign_table_where>
  <size>3</size>
  <minitems>0</minitems>
  <maxitems>3</maxitems>
  </config>
  </TCEforms>
  </selectProperty>
```

By using this flexform method you can select records individually with every plugin..